# Adding new host entries to existing mysql users

Tags: mysql

I have a fairly well defined list of 50 or so users in a mysql database.  All their entires in the user table look something like this:

```
mysql> select user,host,password from user where host = '1.2.3.4';
+--------+---------+----------+
| user   | host    | password |
+--------+---------+----------+
| user1  | 1.2.3.4 | *XXX...  |
| user2  | 1.2.3.4 | *YYY...  |
| user3  | 1.2.3.4 | *ZZZ...  |
etc.
```

What I would like to do is add a second entry for each user so that they can also connect from 10.% using the same password and granting full access from 10.%, but leaving the existing grants in place.

Is there a way I could do this all from within mysql (for automation purposes) or would I have to write a script that dumps the users & password hashes out then issues new grant statements for the 10.% host?

Comment: Check out https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.6/en/mysqluserclone.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO user (user, host, password)
SELECT U.user, '10.x' AS NHost, U.password FROM user AS U
```

Comment: I get `ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'ssl_cipher' doesn't have a default value` when I attempt this. Can anyone enlighten me, which  of the strings above are placeholders for a real value (if any). Or how the syntax might be changed to get this to work?

Comment: Well I see from `SHOW CREATE TABLE user;` that some of these things do not have a default value: `x509_issuer blob NOT NULL,` so I need to add them to the list in the INSERT section and also in the SELECT section.

Comment: I could not get this to work. I had to add a number of columns to the command so that it succeeded without error, but once I had done that I got `ERROR 1877 (HY000): Operation cannot be performed. The table 'mysql.user' is missing, corrupt or contains bad data.` I think the INSERT as given will work in simple cases, but Caveat Administrator.

Comment: Needed to run FLUSH PRIVILEGES; after inserting

Comment: I myself am a beginner at MySQL, but I think that the accepted answer is wrong. I ran across this error because I made (what I think is) the same mistake: trying to add a user to user table with the help of an INSERT INTO command rather than a CREATE USER command. Please see "6.2.8 Adding Accounts, Assigning Privileges, and Dropping Accounts" at the URL https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/creating-accounts.html . It even has a note about this: "Note Direct modification of grant tables using statements such as INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE is discouraged and done at your own risk. "

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the credentials of the user you can also do this.

```
CREATE USER 'some_user_name'@`some_new_host_or_ip` IDENTIFIED BY 'existing_password';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

By the way, as mentioned above post, I couldn't find the `password` field, not sure if it is relevant to the MySQL version. in my case, it was like below. So just if this thing can help others

```
insert into mysql.user (user,host,authentication_string)
    select user,'some_new_host_or_ip',authentication_string 
    from mysql.user where user = 'some_user_name' limit 1

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```